# How can I make a PDF document scale responsively 100% the viewport in asp.net c# razor view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to display a PDF document in razor view but the height and width it displays are too small. The height is too short - just about 100px so one has to scroll so much to go through the document and the user would not be able to view the document properly this way. I have tried to set its height and the height/width of the containing css elements to 100% and yet it does not make any difference.

This is the code I tried to use to display it

```
<div class="panel-body">       
        <embed src="@ViewBag.sourcePath" type="@ViewBag.resourceType" style="width:100%; height:auto; min-height:100%" />
</div>
```

sourcePath is the location of the document.

Then I though of getting the dimensions (i.e. height and width) of the pdf document so I can set the display width on the fly but I dont know the method to get the dimensions of a file in c#. Again my fear in doing it this way is that I want it to be responsive so it can scale properly in different viewports

I will appreciate a guide to achieving this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your panel-body class has height property set to 100 px. 
It is also possible that the div with this class is constrained by other div element in which it is contained.

Anyway you should check yor CSS file or styling atributes on the page. Here's an example of how I display my pdf files.

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewPDFB";
}


<style type="text/css">
    #pdfbox {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        border: 5px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>

<object id='pdfbox' type="application/pdf" data="@Url.Action("ViewPDF", "ControllerName", new { pth = "InputFilePathHere" })"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
public FileStreamResult ViewPDF(string pth)
{            
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(pth, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I have tried to use your method and styles and it didn't make any difference. On inspection, I find that there is another HTML, and body tags inside the PDF document which renders inside the panel-body div. I wish there is a way to remove other display elements of the PDF leaving only the text area because even when I style the panel body with a height of 1000px, it still does t make the document stretch to 1000px height

Comment: Unfortunately informations you provided in the question are insufficient to solve your problem. Please check every element that contains your div or renders this view. I'm pretty sure you will find your answer there.